# Programming with node.js and mongoose. Error id want to pass the value to update registration

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm learning to use with mongoose and node.js when editing to generate a content that gives me the error: 500 TypeError: Can not read property 'ObjectID' of undefined. Check whether the parameter that I send comes empty and is not.
Remove the option and gives me that error when saving the data did not find the method I use to save some registry update.
If I can help as I have code in https://github.com/boneyking/PruebaNode.git

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please provide code or at least a link to the code. A link to your github repo is not cool !!!

Now back to the question... Add an `id` to your model and get it like other types:

```
var SUPER = mongoose.model('Producto',{
    nombre: String,
    descripcion: String,
    precio: Number,
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

SUPER.editar = function(newData, callback){
    SUPER.findOne({id: newData.id}, function(e,o){
        o.nombre = newData.nombre;
        o.descripcion = newData.descripcion;
        o.precio = newData.precio;
        SUPER.save(o);
        callback(o);
    });
}
```